# Python, How to find a specific value when integrating a KDE?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, probability-density

I have a KDE which represent a probability density function (PDF).
Now, I want to get the value of the variable `lower` that satisfies:

`kde.integrate_box_1d(lower, 2.0) == 0.05`

where `0.05` is the "critical value". `2.0` is the upper limit.

So far, I solve it using the follow code:

```
def finder(KDE, critical, lower, upper):
    stop = True
    search = lower
    while stop:
        if KDE.integrate_box_1d(search+0.00001,upper) > critical:
            search += 0.0001
        else: stop = False
    return search, KDE.integrate_box_1d(search,upper)
```

However, this code is inefficient and inaccurate. I wonder if you know a better way to find the correct value of `lower`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this looks like 1d root finding to me. Have a look at

[scipy.optimize](https://www.docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html#scalar-functions)

To be more specific, you could try something like

```
solver = scipy.optimize.brentq # or brenth or ridder or bisect
def finder(KDE, critical, lower, upper):
    def f(search):
        return KDE.integrate_box_1d(search, upper) - critical
    x, r = solver(f, lower, upper, full_output=True)
    assert r.converged
    return x
```

HTH, Paul

Comment: Effectively. A close answer is found the book "Numerical Python: A Practical Techniques Approach for Industry" page 331

Comment: @IvánCastro I'm afraid I don't have that book at hand. I've added some code to the answer. Could you please check whether it does what you want?